# available room booking between two dates and and two times column sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have four columns in my table.

```
STARTDATE               STARTTIME   ENDDATE                 ENDTIME       ROOMCODE
2018-10-16 00:00:00.000 14:00       2018-10-16 00:00:00.000 18:00         CS0001
2018-10-16 00:00:00.000 18:00       2018-10-16 00:00:00.000 22:00         CS0001
```

i want to check booking is available or not

```
       select CONFERENCE_ROOM from COR_CONFERENCE_BOOKING  where 
(cast(STARTDATE as datetime) + cast(START_TIME as time) >= cast('2018-10-16' 
as datetime) + cast(DATEADD(MINUTE, 01, '14:00') as time) 
and cast(STARTDATE as datetime) + cast(START_TIME as time) < cast('2018-10- 
  16' as datetime) + cast('18:00' as time)) 
  or (cast(ENDDATE as datetime) + cast(END_TIME as time) >= cast('2018-10-16' 
   as datetime) + cast(DATEADD(MINUTE, 01, '14:00') as time) 
   and cast(ENDDATE as datetime) + cast(END_TIME as time) < cast('2018-10-16' 
  as datetime) + cast('18:00' as time)) 
    and CONFERENCE_ROOM='CS0001'
```

problem is there i want to select the data if any data found on select query on passing date and time then room is booked otherwise its free.

please solve this query. Its too complicated for me.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the datbase you are using.

Comment: Hi Gordon, four column are there in a table that is already mentioned above, and i am using these query to select the data. My problem is if i pass the date and time in above query and if record is exists then it return the value, that means room is booked other wise room is open for next slot booking.

Comment: Sumit, what Gordon means is that this question cannot be answered unless we know: 1) What the expected output of the query is, and 2) what database server (sql dialect) you are using.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i got the answer posted by someone below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example snippet for MS SQL Server.
I'm assuming that this is your target RDBMS because the example SQL uses that DATEADD function.

It'll only return the first record from the table variable.

Because the second record is out of the range.

```
declare @Table table (
 ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
 STARTDATE date, 
 STARTTIME time, 
 ENDDATE date, 
 ENDTIME time, 
 CONFERENCE_ROOM varchar(6)
);

insert into @Table (STARTDATE, STARTTIME, ENDDATE, ENDTIME, CONFERENCE_ROOM) values
('2018-10-16','14:00:00','2018-10-16','18:00:00','CS0001'),
('2018-10-16','18:00:00','2018-10-16','22:00:00','CS0001');

select ID, CONFERENCE_ROOM 
from @Table t
where (CAST(STARTDATE AS DATETIME) + CAST(STARTTIME as DATETIME)) < (CAST(ENDDATE AS DATETIME) + CAST(ENDTIME as DATETIME))
  and (CAST(STARTDATE AS DATETIME) + CAST(STARTTIME as DATETIME)) >= CAST('2018-10-16 14:00' AS DATETIME)
  and (CAST(ENDDATE AS DATETIME) + CAST(ENDTIME as DATETIME))     <= CAST('2018-10-16 18:00' AS DATETIME)
  and CONFERENCE_ROOM = 'CS0001';
```

If the STARTTIME & ENDTIME are VARCHAR's instead of TIME data types?
Then to avoid errors with trying to convert crap data, you could use TRY_CAST instead.
(If TRY_CAST is available on your version of MS SQL Server)
Because instead of an error a TRY_CAST would return NULL when the conversion fails.

Example:

```
select ID, CONFERENCE_ROOM 
from @Table t
where STARTDATE = ENDDATE
  and TRY_CAST(STARTTIME AS TIME) < TRY_CAST(ENDTIME AS TIME)
  and STARTDATE = CAST('2018-10-16' AS DATE)
  and TRY_CAST(STARTTIME AS TIME) >= CAST('14:00' AS TIME)
  and TRY_CAST(ENDTIME AS TIME)   <= CAST('18:00' AS TIME)
  and CONFERENCE_ROOM = 'CS0001';
```

Comment: @Sumitk Thx, btw this will also work if those STARTTIME and ENDTIME are VARCHAR(8) types.  But it would be best if those are TIME types, so that no-one can enter a value as 'whatever' in them.